# Cannot grep out status line (terminal playback time) from mpv

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, mpv

essentially I'm trying to just run mpv on a video, and after you quit you get some information about the video.

Example:

```
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (hevc 1920x1080 60.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
VO: [gpu] 1920x1080 yuv420p
AV: 00:00:01 / 00:12:32 (0%) A-V:  0.000

Exiting... (Quit)
```

I would like to grep out the AV line, however this line is added before/afterwards (I'm not exactly sure). When running `mpv video_file | grep AV`
The video would play and the terminal would give this little status line

`(Paused) AV: 00:00:02 / 00:00:57 (5%) A-V:  0.000` (random example video, different to the first one)

However after closing mpv there is no output, and its further confirmed when running

`mpv video_file >> test.txt`

giving an output of

```
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (hevc 1920x1080 60.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) (aac 2ch 48000Hz)
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
VO: [gpu] 1920x1080 yuv420p

Exiting... (Quit)
```

suggesting that it places the AV line outside of the output, between VO line and the space line.

Soooo like how would I grep out this line?

Comment: Are you sure that line is standard output and not standard error output? Try to do `mpv video_file 2>&1 | grep "AV"`.

Comment: Ok thank you this worked as intended. May I ask though what the 2>&1 means/does? Thank you!!

Comment: @Edesem `2>&1` means "redirect the standard error out (STDERR) to the standard output out (STDIN). `2` indicates STDERR and `1` indicate STDOUT.  The `2>` means "redirect STDERR" and the `&1` directs the redirection to STDOUT.  

Stepping back a bit, mpv seems like a very awkward tool to use for this purpose.  You can use ffprobe (part of ffmpeg) instead much more easily. Just run this to get a video's duration in sections: `ffprobe -i input_video.mp4 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv=p=0`